# Html/CSS: How to make a table stick to bottom of container, while having the container remain scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` within a `<div>` here:

```
table#message-table{ <!-- table-->
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    position:0;
}
#message-view-area{ <!-- container for table -->
    position: relative;
    flex-grow:1;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100pt;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Basically I want to have the table always stick to the bottom of the `<div>`, but when the table becomes too large, have overflow and make the div scrollable. Which I do, but with this css there's no overflow. Only when I remove `position:absolute;bottom:0;` does the overflow show. However with this method, the table ends up sticking to the top of the div.

How can I keep the overflow, while ensuring that the table sticks to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler approach which uses no absolute positioning and removes the `<div>` wrapper. The body is a `100vh` flexbox container which pushes the table to the bottom of the screen using `flex-end`. The content is scrollable by default when no vertical space remains to show the full contents of the table.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#message-table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<table id="message-table">
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/h4pqnu35/25/)